# Angular Material mat-autocomplete not visible in Browser area

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete, mat-autocomplete

I have the problem that I have a small autocomplete field on the far right, but the text is so long that it goes outside the visible area of the browser.
How can I force the overlay to align to the left?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp0cM.png)

No Idea at the Moment :(

Maybe an manual CSS fix?